# How to properly implement sections in site

Tags: 8, navigation

I am about to create a Page with a Main Menu which is about three levels deep. Each item at the first level should divide the whole page into visual distinct sections.

What would/could be the best choice to implement that with regards to:

- users should not be able to add/delete sections
- possibly no configuration (css classes etc.) should be applied from within the backend, so that each section can only be added in code and put under version control

My first shoot was to create Menu Items from within a module like that:

```
//modules/<mod>/<mod>.links.menu.yml

<mod>
    title: 'Galery'
    parent: standard.front_page
    route_name: <front>
    menu_name: main
```

What works, in such terms that it creates a Menu Item, but:

- users can set a different parent node
- the main problem of adding css classes, script, etc. depending on the link is not solved

I am a bit lost how to go on from here, I would appreciate any help ore ideas!